# Spark SQL sum rows with the same key and appending the sum value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have the following DataFrame.

```
+----+-----+
|lang|count|
+----+-----+
|  en|    4|
|  en|    5|
|  de|    2|
|  en|    2|
|  nl|    4|
|  nl|    5|
+----+-----+
```

How do I sum the values of “count” for each unique language, and appending this value as a new column (thus, without reducing the amount of rows)?

In my example, this would result in:

```
+----+-----+----------------+
|lang|count|totalCountInLang|
+----+-----+----------------+
|  en|    4|              11|
|  en|    5|              11|
|  de|    2|               2|
|  en|    2|              11|
|  nl|    4|               9|
|  nl|    5|               9|
+----+-----+----------------+
```

The DataFrames are constructed through a `map` operation on a `DStream`.

Any suggestions on what would be the best way to achieve this? Is there a more efficient way than using DataFrames?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use one of the following:

- sum over a window:

  ```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

  val df = Seq(
    ("en", 4), ("en", 5), ("de", 2), 
    ("en", 2), ("nl", 4), ("nl", 5)
  ).toDF("lang", "count")

  val w = Window.partitionBy("lang").rowsBetween(
    Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing
  )
  df.withColumn("totalCountInLang", sum("count").over(w))
  ```
- aggregation and join:

  ```
  df.join(df.groupBy("lang").sum(), Seq("lang"))
  ```

With small groups the former solution should be behave slightly better. For larger ones the latter one, optionally combined with broadcast function, is usually proffered.